# JQuery: NOT using document.ready and inserting HTML Tags = is this allowed?

Tags: jquery

is this a valid JQuery usage pattern to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").prepend('<input type="hidden" id="error" value="show">');         
    </script>
```

That is using Jquery to manipulate / insert HTML Tags **when the Document has NOT YET been loaded** (by not using document.ready for the inserting into the DOM)?

(Normally I only use document.ready, but in this case I need to insert some Information into the DOM that then is present, when document.ready is called. This is some kind of "happens-before" relations ship I want to achieve so that I am shure when document.ready is called the inserted Form field is available in the document, as I depend on that information.

Thank you very much
jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but it won't consistently work, as Andrew Bezzub says IE will be the problem (surprise, surprise)

Hard to tell the master plan but for your example could you just not just put this immediately after the `<body>` opening tag:

```
document.write('<input type="hidden" id="error" value="show">');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, but:

- You have to place the script somewhere after the closing tag of the element that you add elements to. That means that the body element is not a good candidate to prepend anything to.
- Make sure that the HTML code is valid. If you are using XHTML you should self close the input element.

Consider using the object creation model instead of innerHTML model:

```
$("#someElement").prepend(
  $('<input/>').attr({ 'type': 'hidden', 'id': 'error' 'value': 'show' })
);
```

This will create the element as a DOM object instead of using innerHTML to parse the HTML code.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you don't like, it's pointless.

Comment: Hello Guffa, thank you very much for your answer!! What a pitty that I cant split the "answer-tick". I really like your ideas and I will search further if this is working in IE too. Your posting helped me to remember JQuery's internal Storage-Implementation and I might simply use this storage facility to storge the state I have to store. So thanks very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

IE may fail loading such HTML - it has problems when someone modifies not fully rendered elements. I think the right choice would be placing such code just after  tag.